# Pushing multiple views onto a stack without seeing the ones inbetween

Tags: ios, persistence, nsoperationqueue, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am trying to give my application a feeling of persistance when switching between multiple parts of the application. 
When they tap on an icon I want it to open directly to the view controller that I was on however, I need to get the View Controller stack to stay the same as it was when they left that part of my app.

The earliest I can seem to present another view controller is in the "viewDIDAppear" method which is problematic because the user sees me going through each view as I am pushing it.

Would presenting view controllers with a NSOperationQueue help me achieve this result. Ultimately I just can't have the user see me stepping through every VC.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be duplicate of [Problem pushing multiple view controllers onto navigation controller stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619147/problem-pushing-multiple-view-controllers-onto-navigation-controller-stack)

Push all your controllers one after another but animate only the last push.

Comment: That is for a navigation controller. I'm using presentModalViewControllerAnimated to push my views.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "stack" I ask, how many UIViewCOntrollers are you thinking on having? Because, you can run into memory problems? You have `viewWillAppear`, that happens before `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in the app delegate method

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

That's how I have done it with a saving of the app state done in

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Then when the user opens the app after fully closing it down it starts up where they left it.

If you need further information on how to persist etc I can provide some examples although they do use a navigation controller.