# Navigation Item rightBarButtonItem and title behaviour broken

Tags: ios, navigation, modalviewcontroller, uinavigationitem

Please could you help me to solve a problem:

I have one navigation controller with initial Controller InitController and 4 view controllers: A, B, C, ModalViewController. I push controllers A->B->C and present ModalView. When I dismiss ModalView and return back to C navigation item is broken: in navigation item I see title "A", right button "Edit" and back button with text"< C", but content is of the C view. After I press back button "< C" I see correct navigation item, i.e. with title "C", right button "previous/next" and back button "< B".

In A in `viewDidLoad`

```
[self.navigationItem setTitle:@"A"];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [self editButton];
if ([self.model gotoB]) {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:B animated:NO]; 
}
```

In B in `viewDidLoad`

```
[self.navigationItem setTitle:@"B"];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [self editButton];
if ([self.model gotoC]) {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:C animated:NO]; 
}
```

In C in `viewDidLoad`

```
[self.navigationItem setTitle:@"C"];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:self.nextPrevRightButton];
if ([self.model showModalView]) {
    [ModalViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
    [ModalViewController setDelegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:ModalViewController animated:YES completion:nil]; 
}
```

In C in `-(void) dismissModalController:(UIViewController *)sender`

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, at the beginning I forgot to mention that A is not an initial controller and that I actually also pushing it to the stack in the initial controller, but I was pushing it with `animated:YES`. That is wrong, i.e. the last modal view controller only need to be presented with `animated:YES`.

An answer to this question [Problem pushing multiple view controllers onto navigation controller stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619147/problem-pushing-multiple-view-controllers-onto-navigation-controller-stack) actually helped me to solve my problem.